# try/throw blocks when writing new front-end for llvm

Tags: c++, exception, llvm

`llvm-config` puts `-fno-exceptions` in the LDFLAGS for linking llvm itself.  Am I right in assuming this means that I cannot use normal C++ try/throw blocks in code (such as a new language front-end) that link against the llvm compiler?  I'm not talking about programs the compiler produces, but the compiler itself.  I do not want to meddle with the output from `llvm-config`, I am sure `-fno-exceptions` is there for a reason..

If I wanted to write a new language front-end for LLVM (for a toy language I'm writing) that linked with the other LLVM code, is there a standard way of handling exceptions in the code for the front-end?

Comment: I think a lot of people are getting confused by your question.  I'm going to edit it for clarity.  You're welcome to roll back my changes if you don't like them.

Answer (score 1):

Just because the LLVM code does not use exceptions does not mean the LLVM environment does not have a exception handling mechanism ... I think you are getting confused here.

Answer (score 1):

[LLVM bug 815](http://hlvm.llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=815) has the rationale: the generated EH code was about 10-20% of the entire binary. It also states that there are exceptions in some parts of the code. Hence, it is reasonable to assume your code can also use exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

The [LLVM documentation](http://llvm.org/docs/ExceptionHandling.html) should tell you what you need to know about how to use exceptions; I don't know why `-fno-exceptions` is specified, or whether you can remove it.

Comment: I did check that, but it seems that that page is for adding exception handling support to the language frontend which we'd write. I was asking about try/throw in the driver code itself.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. Mea culpa.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `-fexceptions` to LDFLAGS in the source level Makefile.am works, but I am not sure if this is a right thing to do.

Comment: Unwinding the stack through code that isn't designed to handle exceptions can result is some pretty bad leaks and other strange things.